# Connecting pairs of dots with arrows in scatterplot (R)

Tags: r, scatter-plot

I have a scatterplot with two set of points. First set of points are of individuals before the intervention, and the second set after the intervention. The simplified code of the plot looks like this:

```
plot(variable_A_pre, variable_B_pre)
points(variable_A_post, variable_B_post)
```

But since each individual gives two points (pre and post intervention), I would like to connect each of these pairs of points with line that has an arrowhead at the end. A similar example would be this:

The closest example I could find is here ( page 7, http://circ.ahajournals.org/content/34/4/597.long ).

Comment: I can't see the example you posted. Is it there?

Comment: Also, try this link for starters: http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/arrows.html Write some code, and if you're still stuck post again and you'll get more useful feedback.

Comment: Thank you, that was it. In fact, I found that library(shape) arrows more choices in terms of arrowheads etc., but the principle is the same. Thank you!